# Ajax post raw html from contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a `contentEditable` div where the user can format whatever they want (*text, images, links, embed videos*).  I'm having trouble uploading it and handling it with my PHP script.

If within my div I have a lot of pictures of big sizes, I either get `"Undefined index: content"`, which it should be defined, OR a `"Fatal error allocated memory"` OR `"unexpected end of input"`. 
What's the proper way to send big files?  Is this a PHP problem of size? 
 Image src are base64 format...

```
var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefinded" ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("cat", checkedVal);
    formData.append("tit", title);
    //content contains all the raw html
    formData.append("content", content);
    xhr.open("POST", "../scripts/admin/uploadpost.php", true);
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            //var percent = (e.loaded/e.total) * 100;
            //progress.value = percent;
        }
    }
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            //var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            console.log(xhr.response);
        }else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
    xhr.send(formData);
```

All I'm doing in PHP is

```
if (isset($_POST["content"])) {
    echo "got it";
}else {
    echo "something wrong"
}
```

Sending 4 imgs (~24MB) works...anything move and I get the "something wrong".  Please advise on how to do this the proper way.
I'm using a MAMP server, php.ini is set to 32MB for max_upload and post.  Sending 5 images of 29MB gives me the "something wrong".

SOLUTION?  Well I guess I have to chunk it and put it all together in PHP.  Spending all day wrestling with this, I found plupload...or just slice my content and check the size (since I'm sure I'll be limited on a shared host anyway to max upload size and time).  So might as well chunk it.  But I still want to know if my problem was with size, with Content-Length posted in the comment.

Comment: Did you tried to increase memory_limit ?

Comment: @3y3skill3r I did in PHP script, then I did in php.ini, set it to 100MB.  I just tried 7 images...got an empty response back.  Inside the inspector, "Content-Length: 58181163"...I understand that's huge...is that why everything is breaking?  Status code is 200...